# arara: Comment a group of arara lines/commands

Tags: arara

How can I comment out a set of arara commands/lines instead of doing it manually by prepending `!` to the word `arara`?

```
% arara: lualatex: { options: [ '-synctex=1',
% arara: --> '-shell-escape','-interaction=nonstopmode' ]} 
% arara: --> if changed(currentFile()) || missing('log')
% arara: --> || missing('aux')
% arara: --> || found ('log','(Undefined control sequence|Error)')
```

Comment: I'm far from an authoritative reference, but `arara` doesn't offer any way whatsoever to “comment” a (set of) directive(s). Prepending `!` to the directive doesn't actually comment it in a way that `arara` recognizes it as a comment, but makes `arara` _not see_ that as a directive. Using `% !arara:` is the same as using `%%arara:` or `% potato:` :-) Besides, the manual doesn't mention anything about comments, so I'd say the answer is “you cannot”. That said, you can wrap the entire `if` conditional in parentheses and add a line `% arara: --> && false`

Comment: You cannot. This is neither intended nor going to be implemented.